# Is there a web site that allows you to draw an ascii chart with boxes and arrows easily?

Tags: website, charts, ascii

Ascii drawings and charts are a useful way of documenting software and can be included directly in source files near the code they document.

I'm looking for an online tool to draw them and be able to move boxes around.
Does something like this exist or should I use my text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use [JavE](http://www.jave.de/). Not exactly online, though.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.asciiflow.com/ allows you to draw boxes and arrows.